# How do I forever run a process on my EC2 mirror using forever.js?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that I SSH in using putty. I have forever.js running on it. However, when I mirror it and start another EC2 instance, it doesn't have 'forever' already running on it. What can I do?

I am running

`nohup forever start index.js`

Comment: Forever should already be running your nodejs app as a background process. You should be able to exit putty. Does it actually kill the process if you exit the terminal session?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, it stops after a while. Not immediately and it's mirror instances never had forever running

Comment: What do you mean by "mirror" instances? Why don't they also have forever running on them? If forever is stopping after a while then have you checked the logs to see if there is any indication why it is stopping?

Comment: New EC2 instances are created using Images/AMI. The image is of an EC2 that has forever running. I am trying to figure out why they don't have forever running on them.

Comment: The processes that are running when you create an AMI don't get automatically started on new instances. The new server goes through a regular boot up process. If you want a process to start automatically, look into how you configure something to start at boot in the OS you are using.